# Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, get, integer

I cannot resolve this problem.
Finally I want to display 'workout.count' in main widget

main.dart

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                      child: Text(workout.count,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                    )
```

main_model

```
void getWorkoutListRealtime() {
    final snapshots =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('workoutlist').snapshots();
    snapshots.listen((snapshot) {
      final docs = snapshot.docs;
      final workoutlist = docs.map((doc) => Workout(doc)).toList();
      workoutlist.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.compareTo(a.createdAt));
      this.workoutlist = workoutlist;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

workout.dart

```
class Workout {

  Workout(DocumentSnapshot doc) {

    this.documentReference = doc.reference;

    this.title = doc.data()['title'];
    this.count = doc.data()['count'];
    final Timestamp timestamp = doc.data()['createdAt'];
    this.createdAt = timestamp.toDate();
  }

  String title;
  String count;
  DateTime createdAt;
  bool isDone = false;
  DocumentReference documentReference;

}
```

Does anyone have ideas?

Of course I research some documents in stackflow,
but I cannot recover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `doc.data()['count']` is an `int` but you need a `String`. So call `doc.data()['count'].toString()`.

`DocumentSnapshot` is not shown but it seems `data` is a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Thank you for amazing answer. I could resolve this

Comment: This helped my particular problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding toString() method.

```
   Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
       child: Text(workout.count.toString(),
       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this in another way:

```
int count;
this.count = doc.data()['count'];
```

to show :  `child: Text(workout.count.toString(),`